# Most probable sum of rolling N dice

Tags: probability

What is the most probable sum of rolling N dice? I can't use mathematical expectation here. But it seems like $3.5n$ is the answer. I know that for 2 dice answer is 7. For 3 is 11 or 10. So how can i prove my assumption for $n$?

Comment: Equations (22)-(24) here have the answer to what the most common sum is: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dice.html.

Comment: How can you produce a roll of 3.5 with one die? “Most probable sum” is not the same thing as “expected value.”

Comment: I gave a full proof in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4236784/177399).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $N>1$ as $N=1$ is easy.

Using expected value, the expected value of the rule is $\mathbb{E}(X)=3.5N$. If this is an integer, then it's the most probable; else the two closest integers are the most probable.

This is because the probability distribution of the sum of rolling $N$ dice follows a upwards curve followed by a downwards curve (you can prove this by induction). These curves are symmetric with respect to the middle, the expected value, and thus the closer you get to the expect value, the more likely that that sum occurs.

Comment: So to get answer i need to use expected value?

Comment: mm, I explained. The graph of sum vs probability looks like a "hill" that increases, then decreases, peaking when the sum is the expected value.

Comment: According to the central limit Theorem, the standardized random variables that are the sums of $N$ dice throws will converge point wise to a random variable with [this density function](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/2600/1*IdGgdrY_n_9_YfkaCh-dag.png)